# Passing a char array reading from file to fopen() generating error as Invalid arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I tried to read file path and name into a char array from a `configuration.txt` file. Then passing the char array to `fopen()`. However, it is generating errors like invalid argument. Instead, if I directly passed the path same to what is in `configuration.txt`, it will succeed. The code is like:

```
    FILE *FIDConfig = fopen(argv[1],"r"); // open configuration file; could be a .txt file
    char inputfname[200], backgroundfname[200], outputfname[200];
    fscanf(FIDConfig, "%s", inputfname); //int fscanf ( FILE * stream, const char * format, ... );
    fscanf(FIDConfig, "%s", backgroundfname);
    fscanf(FIDConfig, "%s", outputfname);

    /* FILE WITH THE RAW DATA */
    errno = 0;
    FILE *FIDIN, *FIDOUT, *FIDBack;  // inputfname = "./data.bin", backgroundfname = "./dbk.bin";
    FIDIN = fopen(inputfname, "rb"); // if changed to FIDIN("./data.bin","rb") it works!
    FIDBack = fopen(backgroundfname, "rb");
```

Comment: Perhaps you should print the contents of `inputfname` to see if it really contains `"./data.bin"` like you think?

Comment: You never check any return codes. Check the results of `fopen` and `fscanf` to ensure those parts are working.